# Plotly Python stacked bar chart formatting

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, seaborn

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart but I can't seem to figure out how I need to input the Y. I'm only trying to measure the amount of experience (exp_mobile) is in each country. So I believe the Y should only be the count of exp_mobile of each country but I can't seem to figure it out.

This is my code:

```
fig = px.bar(df, x="exp_mobile", color="country",
            barmode = 'stack')
 
fig.show()
```

This is what is coming up:
[image]

Comment: Can you please share your dataframe structure i.e. response of ```df.head()```.

Comment: If you are plotting 'amount of experience (exp_mobile) is in each country' then shouldn't one axis be the country name and the other axis be the amount

Comment: Seeing your DataFrame would help us resolve your issue. I imagine that you don't want to be plotting the index on the y-axis, so what happens if you pass the parameter `y="country"`?